# Wicket different handling on page propertyModel depending on RuntimeConfiguration

Tags: wicket

So I have a Wicket 9.10.0 application, running under Java 17.

By the way: Wicket is great work, thanks to everyone working on the project.

We have a page managing mutations to domain entities using different sections to change the data.

Sections will be opened/closed by link attached to the WebMarkupContainer using AjaxEventBehavior("click").

Now if I open section "family" I can change partners and children. If family members already exist, there are shown on the left and are presented as well in edit-components (textfields, datefield) on the right.

Ajax will update the page deleting old or adding new members.

Now this is working fine if I am using RuntimeConfigurationType DEVELOPMENT.

If however we start the application in DEPLOYMENT mode, then somehow the editable values (e.g. first-/lastname) in the underlying property model are nulled out. As soon as I get the component in ListenerRequestHandler (breakpoint) and having a look at the model from the page from the component, the data is already modified.

So somehow I am missing the point between presenting the data in the page in the first request (where all the data is there) and the first ajax request to the page where the data is nulled out!? From my point of view at that point the data would just be retrieved from the page cache (perhaps deserialized), but it should still be the same than after fully rendered and presented the page.

This is reproducable: Starting in DEVELOPMENT mode working, starting application in DEPLOYMENT mode: not working.

So the questions:

- Who is modifying the data in the underlying domain entity? How can I prevent?
- Why is there a difference in both runtime configuration modes?

Any idea/help or pointer would be really much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: The deployment mode should not cause such differences in the behavior. I'd suggest you to push a breakpoint FormComponent#updateModel() and see its stacktrace to find the reason for the `null`-ifying.

Comment: Thanks for the reply :-) The breakpoint is not even touched. I did though set breakpoint on the SerializingPageStore get-/addPage: The page is stored with the correct values, but loaded again (expanding the according section) with the values missing in DEPLOYMENT mode. The exact same application started in DEVELOPMENT mode does correctly store and load the page!!! That is weired! Can you think of something?

Comment: Ok, so now I always start in DEPLOYMENT mode. The only difference is that I am (not) using the CryptoMapper

setRootRequestMapper(new CryptoMapper(getRootRequestMapper(), this));

If I use the CryptoMapper loading from the SerializingPageStore does return domain entities without those values missing. If I don't use it, loading is working fine! 
Thanks a lot for any ideas!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the problem: It was a serialization issue found when isolating to just serialize / deserialize the data. Extremely misleading that it was working (at all!) if in dev-mode. No clue how that correlated.

So implementing `Serializable` on the `MappedSuperClass` fixed the issue!

Thanks.